# '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'NoneType'

Tags: python, nonetype

I am beginner in python, I was writing a code to remove all duplicate numbers from list.

first I tried using for loop but I got similar error

```
lis=[]
lis2=[]
n=print("enter number of items you want in the list \n")
i=0
while (i<n):
    a=input("enter element number ",i+1)
    lis.extend(a)
    i=i+1
for j in lis:
    if j not in lis2:
        lis2.extend(j)
print(" \n list after removing duplicates \n",lis2)
input()
```

Error: `'<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'NoneType'`

Comment: You probably mean `input` function ??(`n=print("enter number of items you want in the list \n")`)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `n=print("enter number of items you want in the list \n")` to:

```
n_ = input("enter number of items you want in the list \n")
n = int(n_)
```

I've also noticed some errors after applying the above changes, which after some fixing becomes:

```
lis=[]
lis2=[]
n_=input("enter number of items you want in the list \n")
n = int(n_)
i=0
while (i<n):
    a=input("enter element number " + str(i+1))
    lis += [a]
    i=i+1
for j in lis:
    if j not in lis2:
        lis2 += [j]
print(" \n list after removing duplicates \n",lis2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `append` instead of `extend` (append is appending one item to a list while extend is adding a list to another list) more in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252703/what-is-the-difference-between-pythons-list-methods-append-and-extend).

`input` receives one argument, more in [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input)

```
lis=[]
lis2=[]
n=input("enter number of items you want in the list \n")
i=0
while (i<n):
    a=input("enter element number " + str(i + 1))
    lis.append(a)
    i=i+1
for j in lis:
    if j not in lis2:
        lis2.append(j)
print(" \n list after removing duplicates \n",lis2)
```